# Can anybody help me with Python enumerate()?

Tags: python, enumerate

Try out the enumerate function for yourself in this quick exercise. Complete the `skip_elements()` function to return every other element from the list, this time using the `enumerate()` function to check if an element is on an even position or an odd position.

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    # code goes here
    
    return ___

print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"])) # Should be ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach'])) # Should be ['Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Peach']
```

My below solution is only returning *"a"* and *"orange"*

I guess that the `for` loop is not working correctly? What am I missing?

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    # code goes here
    for i,alpha in enumerate(elements):
        if i%2==0:
            return alpha
```

Comment: you have the right idea using `enumerate` and `i%2`, you seem to misunderstand how `return` works, try to revise that.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop is working properly the problem is that you are doing a return.When we do a return the control comes out of the loop. If you want to return the elements you can store them in a list and then return

```
def skip_elements(elements):
# code goes here
elements = []
for i,alpha in enumerate(elements):
    if i%2==0:
        elements.append(alpha)
return elements
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using return, which exits the loop. If you just want to print you will want something like:

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    # code goes here
    for i,alpha in enumerate(elements):
        if i%2==0:
            print(alpha)
```

If you want to return a list:

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    even_elements = []
    for i,alpha in enumerate(elements):
        if i%2==0:
            even_elements.append(alpha)
    return even_elements
```

Comment: OPs usage of the function clearly expects it to return a list

Answer (score -1):

Use the slice property of the a list [start:stop:step]

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"][::2]
```

Comment: The problem posed specifically states using the `enumerate` method and checking the parity of the index.